# Google API: use offline access token in javascript

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I started a project using the Google API signin mixed with an angularJS+Firebase app.

What I would like to do is to be able to send an e-mail from one person to another programmatically.

Example: John is logged in, clicks on a button which sends an email to Rachel. But that email is sent using the stored token from Ted, not John's account.

It seems possible using the php library which is not an option here.

So far, I get the token easily using these few lines:

```
var GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess({
                    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://mail.google.com/ profile email'
                }).then(function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    this.storeToken(resp.code);
                });
```

Is it actually possible ? 
A quick search just got me results for php or about how you get a token with the JS library... not how to use it !

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to use a refresh token ( offline access ) to send an email from Ted's account via Javascript.

Sadly this is not possible client side. What your code gives you is a 'code' that you can send to your server using a `$http.post ()` and trade with Google server side for a refresh token.

Here is a guide for how to change that code into a refresh token.
 While you can do this client side it would involve exposing your client secret which you should never do.(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow)

Every time John wants to send an email from Ted's account your application will have to send a request to your server that:

- Sends a request to google with the refresh token and generates an access token (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)
- Sends a seccond request to google using the access token to send the email from Ted's account

I hope that this helped.